# Duet Display App

Tags: graphics

I am facing issues with Duet app running on my Mac mini (Mid 2011) and my iPhone 6s Plus. Although it is claimed to be compatible with these devices, the operation is anything but smooth. The display gets frozen or grey, regardless of the settings selected. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Their support worked well for me, but if you want to get some ideas here - perhaps edit the question - what version of macOS / iOS / Duet app on each is being used? If you list the numeric versions, that helps others if it's just a bug and an update fixes it later, too. +1 even without the edit - someone might have an answer without any details needed.